# wrong address with undetect chrome driver

Tags: python, undetected-chromedriver

Why Do I get agent and profile data on address bar ?
I tried with webdriver and there are no issue with it

```
def new_agent():
   agent_str = [
       "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 "
       "Safari/537.36",
       "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 "
       "Safari/537.36",
       "Mozilla/6.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10) AppleWebKit/600.1.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 "
       "Safari/600.1.25",

return random.choice(agent_str)

    def __init__(self):
       opts = uc.ChromeOptions()
       opts.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

       opts.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 1')
       opts.add_argument('user-data-dir=/home/sun/.config/google-chrome/')
       opts.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
       opts.add_argument(f"user-agent={new_agent()}")
       self.driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),  options=opts)
       self.driver.get("https://example.com") #any link
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misspelled the "user-data-dir" and "user-agent" options.
Replaced with
"--user-data-dir" , "--user-agent" ...